# Scrapy - Send Request or visit other page after Authenticating

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, scrapy

I am trying to crawl an authenticated website with this code. I successfully login to the website but when Im trying to send another FormRequest, I am redirected to the login page again. It seems that session/cookies is not kept by scrapy?

In scrapy docs [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=session), so if i send another request the session is not kept? SO what does `# continue scraping with authenticated session...` this means at all? Do I need to pass again and again the session per request?

Any Idea? Thank you

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = 'login_spider'
     start_urls = ['https://example.com/login']

def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )

def after_login(self, response):
    if "Authenticated" in response.body.decode("utf-8"):
        # continue scraping with authenticated session...
        url = 'https://example.com/search'
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            url,
            formdata={'from': '09/24/2017', 'to': '09/25/2017'},
            callback=self.parse_something
        )

    else:
        self.logger.error("Login failed")
        return

def parse_something(self, response):
    open_in_browser(response)
    self.logger.error(response.body)
    return
```

Comment: Try using `yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formname="<name of form>", formdata={'from': '09/24/2017', 'to': '09/25/2017'},
            callback=self.parse_something
        )` to

Comment: I am sure your login code did not work successful .. try `open_in_browser(response)` inside `after_login` ...

Comment: You did not send any Cookies/Headers ... I am sure the target website did not let you login ... :P If you post the website link and the creds, I can help you

Comment: @Tarun i need to visit first the `/search` page before submitting the `FormRequest`, base on your code, i will send a formrequest to the first response which does not contain the search box.

Comment: @Umair I Successfully logged in on the website and i am sure about this because it redirected to the homepage (which is authenicate user can only view)

Comment: @Joseph, try browsing the `/search` first and then in response submit the form and see if that changes things for you

Comment: @Tarun that's the problem, when i visit the `/search` i got redirected to log in page.

Comment: What happens when you do it in browser?

Comment: When manually doing the steps? Login->redirected to homepage->visit search page->enter query->submit.